# CSS: Multiple problems; opacity also on text, and divs not at right place

Tags: html, css, css-float

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FRE81.png]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>

        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: #00BFFF;
                font-family: "Candara";
                src: url(data/candara.ttf);
            }

            #wrapper {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 800px;
                padding: 15px;
            }

            #wrapper:after {
                content: ".";
                display: block;
                clear: both; 
                height: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
                #header {
                    display: block;
                    background-color: blue;
                }
                    #header .left {
                        display: inline-block;
                        padding: 15px 25px;
                        float: left;
                    }

                        #header .left h1{
                            display: inline-block;
                            font-weight: bold;
                        }

                    #header .right {
                        float: right;
                        display: inline-block;
                    }

                        #header .right span{
                            display: block;
                        }

                #page {
                    display: block;
                    float: left;
                }

                #page .box{
                    display: inline-block;
                    background: black;
                    float: left;
                }

                #header, .box {
                    background: blue;
                    opacity: 0.7;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div class="left">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="right">
                    <span><b>needle:</b> <?php //echo $haystack; ?></span>
                    <span><b>needle:</b> <?php //echo $haystack; ?></span>
                    <span><b>Last update:</b> <?php //echo $lastupdate; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="page">
                <div class="left box">
                    Heey mannn
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the design im aiming for, but its not working at all, instead, i get [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD51Q.png)

And i don't know what im doing wrong, i realy don't. Can you guys help me? All the things i want are in the image. And the red areas are just to mark that i want those boxes there. [I also made a jsfiddle with the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/n4ttA/) If anything is unclear, leave a comment please, instead of just thumbing it down, because its realy hard to explain...

Comment: Opacity will change the overall transparency of the element, including it's child elements, for the background you'll need something like a background color with RGBA http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/

Comment: as LEIPiC said.. You can also use a gif 1px*1px X% transparent image set as background (repeat) to achieve the effect.. You might want to checkout a grid system to achieve these and more complex results faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a transparent background, use `rgba` or `hsla` colors.

Example:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7); /* Blue, opacity 0.7*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's code, which renders what you have in your design image. Tested only in Chrome. This is not optimal nor an optimized solution but should let you continue with your design.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        body {
            background: #00BFFF;
            font-family: "Candara";
            src: url(data/candara.ttf);
        }

        #wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 800px;
        }

        #header {
            width: 720px;
            height: 100px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 10px 40px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
            -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
            border-radius: 13px;
        }

        .title_area {
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
            margin-top: 12px;
            padding: 25px 25px;
            background: #f00;
            -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
            border-radius: 13px;
        }

        #header .info_area {
            float: right;
            width: 200px;
            height: 60px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            padding: 5px;
            background: #f00;
            -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
            border-radius: 13px;
        }

        #page {
            clear: both;
            margin: 20px 0px;
        }

        .content {
            float: left;
            width: 380px;
            height: 500px;
            padding: 20px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
            -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
            border-radius: 13px;
        }

        .up_right {
            float: left;
            width: 320px;
            height: 240px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
            -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
            border-radius: 11px;
        }

        .down_right {
            float: left;
            width: 320px;
            height: 200px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
            -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
            border-radius: 11px;
        }

        .close {
        clear: both;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="title_area">
                <h1>Title</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="info_area">
                <div><b>needle:</b> <?php //echo $haystack; ?></div>
                <div><b>needle:</b> <?php //echo $haystack; ?></div>
                <div><b>Last update:</b> <?php //echo $lastupdate; ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="page">
            <div class="content">
                Heey mannn
            </div>

            <div class="up_right">
                Hou hou
            </div>

            <div class="down_right">
                Yeah
            </div>
            <div class="close"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

rgba is a good solution, but 
It might be cross browser issue as well

try this, instead of just opacity:0.7

```
opacity: 0.7;
-moz-opacity: 0.7;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.7);
```